# Need help making my DataGridView sortable

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a DataGridView that I populate with data that I get from a web service.

`AdminTool.adminWS.templateListDTO[] templateList = null;`

```
AdminTool.adminWS.OwordBeanService owClient = new AdminTool.adminWS.AdminBeanService();

GetAllTemplateList templateListParameter = new GetAllTemplateList();

templateListParameter.UserLanguage = "EN";

templateList = owClient.GetAllTemplateList(templateListParameter);

dataGridTemplateList.DataSource = templateList;
dataGridTemplateList.Refresh();
```

I've set SortMode to Automatic for all of the columns in my grid, but it won't sort. I have done some research online and from the articles I've read they speak of a sortable BindingList, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Should I be converting what I get from the web service into a sortable BindingList? If so, how can I do that? Is there some other way to make my grid sortable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This jquery site helped me do the exact same thing in a report.
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid8.php

Comment: I'm working with C#. Sorry, I neglected to mention that in my posting.